# scandir to only show folders, not files

Tags: php

I have a bit of PHP used to pulled a list of files from my image directory - it's used in a form to select where an uploaded image will be saved. Below is the code:

```
$files = array_map("htmlspecialchars", scandir("../images"));       

foreach ($files as $file) {
 $filelist .= sprintf('<option value="%s">%s</option>' . PHP_EOL, $file, $file );
}
```

It works fine but shows all files and folders in 'images', does someone know a way to modify this code so that it only shows folder names found in the 'images' folder, not any other files.

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The easiest and quickest will be [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) with **`GLOB_ONLYDIR`** flag:

```
foreach(glob('../images/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
    $dirname = basename($dir);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, this worked and shows just folders but also shows "../images/" before the folder name. Because of the way my SQL database is designed I don't need that beginning part. Is there a way to edit it to remove it? Thanks

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to do it, [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) is one of them

Comment: replace basename by dirname($dir);

Comment: No need for the 2nd arg (`GLOB_ONLYDIR`), just add a slash after the asterisks: `../images/*/`

Answer (score 9):

Function `is_dir()` is the solution :

```
foreach ($files as $file) {

  if(is_dir($file) and $file != "." && $file != "..") $filelist .= sprintf('<option value="%s">%s</option>' . PHP_EOL, $file, $file );

}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried your first answer and the drop down gave two choices '.' or '..', then I tried you edit and get nothing at all. Any ideas? thanks

Comment: this still gives a blank drop down, but I have it working now using the other method. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 8):

The **is_dir()** function requires an absolute path to the item that it is checking.

```
$base_dir    = get_home_path() . '/downloads'; 
//get_home_path() is a wordpress function
$sub_dirs = array();
$dir_to_check = scandir($dir);
foreach ($dir_to_check as $item){
  if ($item != '..' && $item != '.' && is_dir($base_dir . "/" . $item)){
    array_push($sub_dirs, $item);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use your `array_map` function combined with `glob`

```
$folders = array_map(function($dir) {
    return basename($dir);
}, glob('../images/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR));
```

Yes, I copied a part of it of [dev-null-dweller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258674/dev-null-dweller), but I find my solution a bit more re-useable.

Answer (score 1):

I try this

```php
    <?php

$dir = "../";

$a = array_map("htmlspecialchars", scandir($dir));

$no = 0; foreach ($a as $file) {

  if ( strpos($file, ".") == null && $file !== "." && $file !== ".." ) {
    $filelist[$no] = $file; $no ++;
  }

}
print_r($filelist);
?>
```